# How to set default value when inserting on empty selection in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm keeping a record of all changes to a table of data, so that the table stores the old value and new value of any change made. I'm using a `insert` with a `select` to get the old value. This works well, but doesn't respect the change record tables default value for the old value.

schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rovers (
    name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    location TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS change_record (
    rover TEXT NOT NULL,
    key TEXT NOT NULL,
    timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,

    oldValue TEXT DEFAULT "",
    newValue TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(rover, key, timestamp)
);
```

When adding or updating, the following is used:

```
INSERT INTO change_record (rover, timestamp, key, oldValue, newValue) VALUES (
    "curiosity"
    "2019-10-29T09:42:32.865Z",
    "location",
    (SELECT location FROM rovers WHERE name = "curiosity"),
    "surface"
);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO rovers (name, location) VALUES ("curiosity", "surface")
```

If there's already a row for `name = "curiosity"`, then `oldValue` is set correctly in `change_record`, but if the rover doesn't exist then `oldValue` is set to `NULL`.

The following works, but seems inefficient to me (requiring two selects):

```
INSERT INTO change_record (rover, timestamp, key, oldValue, newValue) VALUES (
    "curiosity"
    "2019-10-29T09:42:32.865Z",
    "location",
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT location FROM rovers WHERE name = "curiosity") THEN
            (SELECT location FROM rovers WHERE name = "curiosity"),
        ELSE
            ''
    END,
    "surface"
);
```

Is it possible to do this without a `CASE` block, with `IFNULL` somehow? Also, is it possible to use the default value defined in `CREATE TABLE`, without having to duplicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to avoid the 2 `SELECT`s inside the `INSERT` query, you can use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) which will return either the column value of `location` if it exists, or `NULL` if it does not exist. 
Then use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) to change the `NULL` value to `''`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT location FROM rovers WHERE name = 'curiosity')
INSERT INTO change_record (rover, key, timestamp, oldValue, newValue) VALUES (
    'curiosity',
    '2019-10-29T09:42:32.865Z',
    'location',
    COALESCE((SELECT location FROM cte), ''),
    'surface'
);
```

I kept the order of the columns just like your code, but if it's not a typo, I think that `key` and `timestamp` should be interchanged because as they are now they will get the values: `'2019-10-29T09:42:32.865Z'` and `'location'` respectively.

Comment: oh yeah, `key` and `timestamp` are in the wrong order. good spot. I've updated the question with the correct order

Comment: This simplified it, though I chose to use `IFNULL((SELECT location FROM cte), ''),` which works the same way. It would have been nice to be able to automatically use the table column default, but I can't see how that's possible.